# Jquery on page load in stead of onclick

Tags: jquery, onclick, onload

I like this jquery script to load on pageload instead of load on click.
I changed the following:

```
<script>
    $('.error').on('click', function(){
        $(this).notifyMe(
            'bottom', // Position
            'error', // Type
            'Lorem Ipsum Text', // Title
            'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing', // Description
            200 // Velocity of notification
        2000 // (optional) Time of delay to close automatically
        );
    });
</script>
```

to:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(this).notifyMe(
            'bottom', // Position
            'error', // Type
            'Lorem Ipsum Text', // Title
            'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing', // Description
            200 // Velocity of notification
        2000 // (optional) Time of delay to close automatically
        );
    });
</script>
```

But it doesn't load the notifyer.
It's based on this script: http://www.jqueryrain.com/?koLHvt8W

Can somebody tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Your `this` refers to different objects. Change it to `$(".error")` in the second version to keep it consistent. Also remember that [*page load* and *document ready* are not the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.error').notifyMe(
        'bottom', // Position
    'error', // Type
    'Lorem Ipsum Text', // Title
    'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing', // Description
    200 // Velocity of notification
    2000 // (optional) Time of delay to close automatically
    );
});
```